# How to get all repos that contain a certain branch on Github's GraphQL API

Tags: github, github-api, github-graphql

I have many repositories and some of them contain a branch that has the same name. I want to be able to fetch all the repositories that contain a specific branch name. This is what I have so far but I can't seem to figure out how to add the necessary query.

```
{
  repositoryOwner(login: "dev") {
    repositories(first: 1) {
      nodes {
        name
        refs(first: 15, refPrefix: "refs/heads/") {
          edges {
            node {
              name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to request all repositories which have a ref with `qualifiedName` as `<branch_name>`. Then in your client side remove all null results :

```graphql
{
  repositoryOwner(login: "JakeWharton") {
    repositories(first: 100) {
      nodes {
        ref(qualifiedName: "gh-pages") {
          repository {
            name
            description
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20repositoryOwner(login%3A%20%22JakeWharton%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20repositories(first%3A%20100)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ref(qualifiedName%3A%20%22gh-pages%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20repository%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20description%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

With [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) & [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to exclude the `null` results it would be :

```bash
curl -s -H "Authorization: token YOUR_TOKEN" \
     -d '{ 
          "query": "{ repositoryOwner(login: \"JakeWharton\") { repositories(first: 100) { nodes { ref(qualifiedName: \"gh-pages\") { repository { name } } } } } }"
      }' https://api.github.com/graphql | \
      jq -r '.data.repositoryOwner.repositories.nodes[] | select(.ref != null) | .ref.repository.name'
```

You will have to go [through pagination](https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/) if there are more than 100 repos

You can also use [aliases](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases) in case you need to find a combination of branch name in a single repo (or one of them). For instance looking for branch `gh-pages` & `1.0` :

```graphql
{
  repositoryOwner(login: "JakeWharton") {
    repositories(first: 100) {
      nodes {
        branch1: ref(qualifiedName: "1.0") {
          repository {
            name
            description
          }
        }
        branch2: ref(qualifiedName: "gh-pages") {
          repository {
            name
            description
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20repositoryOwner(login%3A%20%22JakeWharton%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20repositories(first%3A%20100)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20branch1%3A%20ref(qualifiedName%3A%20%221.0%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20repository%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20description%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20branch2%3A%20ref(qualifiedName%3A%20%22gh-pages%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20repository%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20description%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)